# Python Help for URL Segregation

Tags: python, python-3.x

If I have a URL `www.somewebsite/category/category-xyz` and I want to segregate all such category URLs from a list of URLs that I already have, how do I do it in Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [urlparse](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/urllib.parse.html#module-urllib.parse)

```
>>> from urllib.parse import urlparse
>>> url = "http://www.test.com:8080/cat1/cat2"
>>> parsed = urlparse(url)
>>> parsed
ParseResult(scheme='http', netloc='www.test.com:8080', path='/cat1/cat2', params='', query='', fragment='')
>>> parsed.path
'/cat1/cat2'
>>> parsed.path.split("/")
['', 'cat1', 'cat2']
```

If you notice above URL parse will take care of breaking out the things you don't care about, making your string processing easier. In the example above you can see it cleanly breaks out the protocol, host, and port and leaves you with just the path to operate on.  Additionally if there was any additional query parameters it would break those out too.

Once you have the "path" string, you can simply parse it as you would any string. since your path will always start with a "/" you can probably just omit that from your string split

```
>>> parsed.path.split("/")[1:]
['cat1', 'cat2']
```

Please note; if your URL does not contain a path this will probably fail.  If you need more details you should provide the end result you're looking for in the question

Comment: I don't get the last line. why is there a blank item in the first position? Please explain?

Comment: split() is just the built in string split method.  It simply takes "/" as an input and breaks up the rest of the string accordingly.  Since the string begins with a "/" it creates the first entry as empty string.  URL parse breaks apart the rest of the info just getting you the path bits of interest,  which you can then operate on like a normal string.